# MVC Razor syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

How would I write this in Razor?

```
<%: Model[0].AddressLatitude %>
```

The following does not work:

```
@Model[0].AddressLatitude
```

Comment: Is your model really the same?

Comment: We have to see more html that surrounds that line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might need to declare your model is enumerable to let the view know it's an array:

```
@Model IEnumerable<YourNamespace.YourModelType>
//@Model[0].AddressLatitude <-- there appears to be no indexer when using IEnumerable
@foreach (var item in @Model) {
  @item.AddressLatitude
  break;
}
```

Comment: @Oskar: You might be right. In that case you could only use a foreach-loop and break after the first item. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: IEnumerable<T> does not have an indexer.

Comment: that is obviously not the problem as he could use it before... probably his model isn't the same